# How to set breakpoint simultaneously on all constructors in gdb for a C++ object?

Tags: c++, constructor, gdb, breakpoints

I have a C++ object which has 20 constructors or so and I want to know which particular constructor is getting called.

Comment: If you have that many constructors I would say your design is flawed. Or your implementation of the design is.

Comment: Why can not you use `s` command to enter into the ctor?

Comment: You should be able to figure out which constructor is being called from the calling code. If you still want to set a breakpoint then you can call some dummy method from all the 20 constructors and set a breakpoint there.

Comment: @VTT Funny, I made the exact same suggestion about the dummy method, but deleted the comment, because I wasnt sure if it makes any sense. I have to admit that I rarely use a debugger

Comment: Just run `break myNamespace::myClass::myClass` and gdb will break on every constructor.

Comment: No user will ever use or know about 20 constructors. Please review your design.

Comment: @VTT That is too cumbersome.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and its not uncommon to implement copy, move and default constructor. Adding two or more constructors with argument lists will give you more constructors than you want to manually break on.
And in addition to that, implementing constructors, that take a template class or even variardic agrument list can get you up to 20 constructors without beeing confusing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude . Sure Will see if redesign is possible.

Comment: Probably `rbreak`? (breakpoints matching the regular expression). https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rbreak`. See [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html):

> rbreak regex
>
> Set breakpoints on all functions matching the regular expression
>   regex. This command sets an unconditional breakpoint on all matches,
>   printing a list of all breakpoints it set. Once these breakpoints are
>   set, they are treated just like the breakpoints set with the break
>   command. You can delete them, disable them, or make them conditional
>   the same way as any other breakpoint.

Example:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() {}
  Foo(int) {}
};

int main() {
  Foo f1;
  Foo f2(1);
  return 0;
}
```

gdb session:

```
[ ~]$ gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) rbreak Foo::Foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004dc: file so-rbr.cpp, line 3.
void Foo::Foo();
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4004eb: file so-rbr.cpp, line 4.
void Foo::Foo(int);
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x00000000004004dc in Foo::Foo() at so-rbr.cpp:3
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x00000000004004eb in Foo::Foo(int) at so-rbr.cpp:4
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run `break myNamespace::myClass::myClass` and gdb will break on every constructor.

For example if you want to break on the creation of any runtime_error, which has at least 2 constructors you can run `break std::runtime_error::runtime_error`. The gdb output will be something like this:

```
Breakpoint 4 at 0xaf20 (4 locations)
```

This is indicating, that the breakpoint is set to multiple constructors. To check the locations of the breakpoint running `info breakpoints` will deliver output like this:

```
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   <MULTIPLE>         
1.1                         y     0x000000000000af20 <std::runtime_error::runtime_error(char const*)@plt>
1.2                         y     0x000000000000b300 <std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)@plt>
1.3                         y     0x000000000000b460 <std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@plt>
1.4                         y     0x000000000000b5e0 <std::runtime_error::runtime_error(char const*)@plt>
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting breakpoint on only one constructor for break std::runtime_error::runtime_error

Comment: Did you run `break std::runtime_error::runtime_error` or `break std::runtime_error::runtime_error()`?

Comment: b  std::runtime_error::runtime_error. Just copy pasted yours. Maybe some older gdb version or code not compiled in debug ?

Comment: That maybe the case. It is also possile, that one breakpoint corresponds to multiple locations. `info breakpoints` will list all locations of breakpoints, so you can check this one. Also check if you are compiling with debug information `-g` for `gcc/g++`and `clang/clang++`.